# Call facebook graphrequest multiple times

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-asynctask

i'm developpig an app in which i need to call the fb graphrequest multiple times , but those calls needs to be one after the other, the first one will get me the user friends, and the other calls will be done in a loop (for each friend ) get the "likes" that that friend made, now with the code that i made, the first one gives me the friends but the second one (the loop instruction) won't work, i guess it has somehing to do with the async calls but i don't know how to make them serial calls, here's my code :

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONArray array, GraphResponse response) {
                    JSONObject jsonArray = response.getJSONObject();

                    try {
                        length = jsonArray.getJSONArray("data").length();


                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            AlertDialog a = new AlertDialog.Builder(liste_peronalisee.this).create();
                            a.setTitle("Erreur");
                            id[i] = jsonArray.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                            a.setMessage(id[i]);
                            a.show();


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

    request.executeAsync();
 for(int i=0;i<id.length;i++)
    request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
           AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/".concat(id[i]).concat("/likes"),
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    JSONObject jsonArray = response.getJSONObject();

                    try {
                        length = jsonArray.getJSONArray("data").length();


                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            AlertDialog a = new AlertDialog.Builder(liste_peronalisee.this).create();
                            a.setTitle("Erreur");
                            id[i] = jsonArray.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                            a.setMessage(id[i]);
                            a.show();


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

    request.executeAsync();
```

i need a quick answer, thanks in advance